# How to include space between the table name in command line for MySql?

Tags: mysql, command-line, command-prompt

I have installed `xampp` and using `phpMyAdmin`to create a table named as `'student name'` I didn't include the underscore as the convention says.

Now, I am trying to access it via command prompt and when I put in the following query-

`SELECT * FROM test.student name;`

It says -

`test.student` does not exist.

I tried putting in the underscore for hit and trial but didn't work.
I looked in phpMyadmin and tried running a query from there to see how was it calling the table name But I see it literally puts ``  in everything 
for example

> SELECT * FROM `student name``;

Tried doing the same but it didn't work in command prompt.

So how to do it?

Comment: use double quotes `"student name"`

Comment: And don't do that again, never use spaces to identifiers. As you said yourself, use the convention.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Is this a command prompt's rule or mysql's rule? 
I assume command prompt's?

Comment: It is just a convention that will make it easier for everyone who reads and uses your code. It's not a rule that's why the double quotes for. Back in the old days that only databases and clients existed you use it to name and create reports well formatted nowadays you let this work to the application layer.

Comment: Quote the table name with backticks, not single or double quotes. Also, never use spaces in table or column names. Never, ever!

Comment: @SloanThrasher You are wrong about the double quotes, it is IN the SQL ansi standards and backticks wont work for the command line. I agree with you about the "never ever" though :)

Comment: @JorgeCampos Well, backticks seem to work for me in command prompt.

Comment: It works like it does in phpMyadmin. I seem to have made a mistake with the syntax earlier. Thanks for your tips!

Comment: @Shad Yeah, you are right backticks do work in Mysql only. Double quotes is sql standard to that purpose. I was wrong about saying that it wont work. I was thinking on sql ansi rather than mysql only. Sorry for that to Sloan.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Sorry bro you were right about the backticks. But wrong about the double quotes.

Comment: @JorgeCampos But it doesn't seem to work with double quotes! So he is right I guess?

Comment: Yes, indeed he is right but only for mysql that doesn't follow the SQL Ansi (what a surprise yeeeey, ¬¬) Tested on sql fiddle, works in every database except in mysql.

Comment: Woh, The more we know! :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I was making a syntax error. Putting the table name with backticks(`) solves the problem.

**Though as pointed out in the comments, Identifiers such as a table name should never ever have a space between them.**